# strcat() deleting strings when trying to create a space-separated string. (C programming)

Tags: c, string, concatenation, strcat

I have been struggling with this problem for the last few hours, and it is one of the stranger problems I have encountered in my 3 years learning programming.

I am trying to create a longer, space-separated string by concatenating strings found in argv from stdin. This is the code I originally wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>

#include "stringtable.h"
#include "strhash.h"
#include "auxlib.h"


int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    int c;
    char* filename;

    while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "@:Dly")) != -1){
        switch(c){
            case '@': 
                printf("@ detected\n");
                char* debugString = optarg;
                int pos_in_input = optind;
                while(argv[pos_in_input][0] != '-' && argv[pos_in_input] != NULL){
                    strcat(debugString, " ");
                    strcat(debugString, argv[pos_in_input]);
                    pos_in_input++;
                    if(argv[pos_in_input] == NULL){break;}                  
                }
                printf("%s\n", debugString);
                break;
            case 'D':
                printf("D detected\n");
                break;
            case 'l':
                printf("l detected\n");
                break;
            case 'y':
                printf("y detected\n");
                break;
            default :
                printf("default detected\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Most of the above is my unfinished options handling. The code segment of interest is in the switch statement under case : "@". The while loop is supposed to be creating the debugString by concatenating the strings found in argv, stopping when a string begins with "-" or when the end of argv is reached. I am also adding spaces between the strings with "strcat(debugString, " ");" It is adding spaces that is giving me trouble.

If I concatenate all the strings without adding spaces in this way:

```
            while(argv[pos_in_input][0] != '-' && argv[pos_in_input] != NULL){
                strcat(debugString, argv[pos_in_input]);
                pos_in_input++;
                if(argv[pos_in_input] == NULL){break;}                  
            }
```

I get the following:

```
 Input: -@what is going on here?
Output: @ detected
        whatisgoingonhere?
```

This is how I expected it to work. However, if I run the code that adds spaces:

```
            while(argv[pos_in_input][0] != '-' && argv[pos_in_input] != NULL){
                strcat(debugString, " ");
                strcat(debugString, argv[pos_in_input]);
                pos_in_input++;
                if(argv[pos_in_input] == NULL){break;}                  
            }
```

Then I get the following as output:

```
 Input: -@what is going on here?
Output: @ detected
        what  going on here?
```

Notice the two spaces between 'what' and 'going'. My program is still correctly adding spaces, even though for some reason a word is getting deleted. I have tried this with many different inputs, it is always the second string in input that gets deleted. Anyone know what is going on?

P.S. Compiling with gcc -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu99 -lm

None of the include files that I created are used in this piece of code, so the problem is not something in my includes.

Comment: FYI, `strcat` is considered unsafe in practically every circumstance.  Use `strlcat` or `snprintf` as replacements (`strncat` is not quite a suitable replacement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code of interest starts with:

```
            char* debugString = optarg;
```

This makes the `debugString` pointer point to the *same place* that `optarg` points to. This does not allocate a "new" string in any way. By calling `strcat(debugString,  ...)`, you are overwriting whatever else happens to appear in memory after the end of `optarg`. Chaos will ensue.

To address this problem, try:

```
            char debugString[1000];
            strcpy(debugString, optarg);
```

This will allocate 1000 bytes for you to stuff bits of string into using `strcat`. It is *your* responsibility to ensure that you do not write past the end of the `debugString` buffer (so if you find you have more than 1000 bytes to concatenate, you'll have to decide what you want to do with that).

Comment: I bow to your mastery. *bows*. That fixed it. Thanks. Time to go relearn pointers.